# Consume stream with unique values for each consume

Tags: spring, project-reactor

I have defined this as global:

```
Processor<Integer, Integer> p = RingBufferProcessor.create("test", 32);
Stream<List<Integer>> s = Streams.wrap(p).distinct().buffer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).log().unbounded();
```

On construtor:

```
s.consume(i -> System.err.println(Thread.currentThread() + " data=" + i));
```

Now i call this function twice:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    p.onNext(i % 3);
}
```

The distinct works fine and i get the first time consume. When i call this method again he is still remember the distinct and doesn't trigger the consume.

Is there any option to clean distinct after every time we consume. The idea that i need to achieve is that i will buffer all input and every time i will consume only unique items..

Someone has any idea?

Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deep search i have arrived to conclusion that i believe this is not an option. The thing that i managed to do is that when i consume i am converting to Set. This way every time stream is consuming i am working only on unique values